# How to convert received bytes in Boost C++ to a unsigned int and to a vector of unsigned int

Tags: python, c++, sockets, boost, data-conversion

I'm sending via Python TCP Socket an unsigned integer to a client written in Boost C++.
I would like to know how to convert the received bytes in the Boost C++ socket into an unsigned integer.

**Python Socket Server**

```
import socket
import struct

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    print("listening..")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)

        # SENDING 10 AS AN UNSIGNED INTEGER
        conn.send(struct.pack("I",10))
```

**C++ Boost Client Socket**

```
#include <boost/asio/local/stream_protocol.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

using namespace std;

// CREATE SOCKET
boost::asio::io_service io_context;
boost::asio::streambuf sb;
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 10000);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_context);
socket.connect(ep);

// READ 4 BYTES
boost::asio::read(objSocket, sb,boost::asio::transfer_exactly(4), ec))

cout << "\nreceived: '" << &sb << "'\n";

// CONVERT 4 BYTES TO UNSIGNED INT
boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type bufs = sb.data();

string str(boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs), boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs) + sb.size());

sb.consume(sb.size());

std::stringstream sstr(str);

unsigned int receivedInt = 0;

sstr >> receivedInt;

cout << "\nReceivedInt: "<< length;
```

PS: The C++ client receives the data (4bytes) but I can't convert it to uint.

And how to convert bytes to a vector of unsigned int?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Python side you don't specify byte order for your bytes stream. So it will depend on the machine, it could be *little-endian* or *big-endian*. It may lead to problems.

You can force bytes stream to be sent for example in *little-endian* by:

```
conn.send(struct.pack("<I",10))    # added <
```

In C++, by calling `sstr >> receivedInt` you perform *formatted* reading of data. It could work if your stream held "10" as string - 2 characters, but your stream contains 4 bytes - binary representation of 10 as decimal. You have to just merge values of all bytes into `unsigned int`, which is easy because you know the order of bytes:

```
boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type bufs = sb.data();
string str(boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs), boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs) + sb.size());
sb.consume(sb.size());
uint32_t received = 
    (str[0] & 0xFF) 
  | (str[1] << 8) & 0xFF00 
  | (str[2] << 16) & 0xFF0000
  | (str[3] << 24);
std::cout << received << std::endl;  // 10
```

Data is sent in *little-endian* order so when merging it into uint32 data must be shifted like this:

```
[str[3] | str[2] | str[1] | str[0]]
```

Before shifting *char* is promoted to be *int* with extending a bit of sign, so you have to perform bitwise AND with proper masks to zero most left bits.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just tried your solution, and when I send struct.pack("<I", 1230) at the C++ side I get 974. Do you know why?

Comment: nice thank you very much, it worked! Could you please just explain me briefly why do we convert from buffer to string to integer. Is there a way of converting from buffer to integer directly?

Comment: @Hangon The easiest way is to define `uint32_t received` and then just make a buffer for this integer: `boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&received,4),ec);`. And it is enough. 4 bytes will be directly read into `received`. But in this case you have to handle little/big endian. For big-endian `recevied`'s bytes should be reversed.